# Como obter a carga do CPU do servidor

Tags: php, cpanel

Estou à procura de maneiras de como obter a carga do CPU do servidor, anteriormente utilizava scripts onde havia a função `exec()` que neste outro servidor tem a função desabilitada por segurança.

Haveria outra maneira de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a biblioteca  [**PHPSysInfo**](http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/) que é *open source* e não usa `exec()`, algumas das informações que podem ser obtidas são: Tempo de atividade, estatísticas de uso de memória RAM, temperatura, número de processos, versão do Kernel, etc.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/phpsysinfo/index.php?disp=bootstrap)</kbd>

Uma outra alternativa é o [**Linfo**](http://linfo.sourceforge.net/), é *cross-platform* e pode obter informações como: Estatísticas de uso de memória RAM, espaço em disco, tempo de atividade, versão do Kernel, temperatura, etc.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://linfo.sourceforge.net/demo/)</kbd>

Comment: Acabei instalando a biblioteca PHPSysInfo no servidor, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode usar a função `sys_getloadavg()`.

Essa função retorna um array contendo 3 valores que representam uma média da carga do sistema nos últimos 1, 5 e 15 minutos respectivamente.

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php)

Comment: Olá, uma boa alternativa já que não é possível utilizar a função exec() no servidor. Obrigado!